# Sort with field of type String containing numbers and letters both

Tags: apex, sort

What is the best way to sort a List of String containing letters and numbers as values?

I have tried couple of ways to sort, but with nothing I could make it work.

1. Using a sort method of list
2. Using comparable interface

Small example what I am trying to achieve

```
List<String> strList = new List<String>{'1 test', '2 test', '10 test', '13 test'};
```

With every method I use for sorting i get the  result like

```
{(1 test, 10 test, 13 test, 2 test)}
```

However I am trying to achieve `{(1 test, 2 test, 10 test, 13 test)}`

I know it is happening because salesforce do the sorting lexicographically. But is there a way to achieve what I am after ?

Comment: list.sort() method does wat u want.. unless u want the opposite of wat u r asking.. chk this out http://imgur.com/k1n7qaG

Comment: just edited the question description, Thanks @VamsiKrishna for pointing this out.

Comment: does the value always starts with a number and has a space between the number and the text ?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna  Value will always start with  a number, but there could be a space and not.

Comment: u can extract the leading number using regex pattern matching and use that to do number based sorting instead of string based sorting.

Answer (score 2):

Given the pattern you have described, you could certainly try to parse out the starting number and sort on that.

```
public class NumericString implements Comparable
{
    final Integer numericValue;
    public final String value;
    public NumericString(String value)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.numericValue = getStartingDigits(value);
    }
    public Integer compareTo(Object instance)
    {
        NumericString that = (NumericString)instance;
        if (this.numericValue == null) return 1;
        if (that.numericValue == null) return -1;
        return this.numericValue - that.numericValue;
    }

    public static Integer getStartingDigits(String value)
    {
        if (String.isNotBlank(value))
        {
            try
            {
                return Integer.valueOf(value.splitByCharacterType()[0]);
            }
            catch (TypeException tex) { /*NaN*/ }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The above should be simpler with regular expressions, but I couldn't get them to work. I also put nulls last, but you could put them first by reversing `this` and `that` in your null checks.

Comment: As per the comments above, sometimes there's a space, sometimes there isn't.  Sounds like a bit of a data issue, but the code probably needs to handle it. Maybe use the splitByCharacterType() instead of split(' ')?

Comment: @NickCook Good catch. Seems like regex should be simple, but why create two problems?

Comment: Hi @AdrianLarson , I am not sure how the above code will will work when the list elements are like {'1 test', '2 hcg', '2 abc, '13 abc'};